# How to specify SellerWarrantyDescription in Amazon MWS API?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am sending product feed, price feed, image feed and inventory feed successfully to Amazon with all fields except warranty information. Now I am stuck at sending SellerWarrantyDescription field and I have no idea how I should specify this field on my xml feeds and send it to Amazon API. I found most of the information I needed from this [Amazon documentation link](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V353515335_.pdf) and amazon forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The warranty information has been passed like the example given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>34L9195-new</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>B003GDHZTM</Value>
      </StandardProductID>  
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
    <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
    </Condition>          
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>IBM 34L9195 9GB 10K 80PIN HARD DRIVE</Title>
        <Brand>IBM</Brand>
        <Description>IBM 34L9195 9GB 10K 80PIN HARD DRIVE</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Covered by comprehensive warranty</BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint>Ships fast</BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint>Refurbished by certified technicians</BulletPoint>
        <ShippingWeight unitOfMeasure="LB">5</ShippingWeight>
        <Manufacturer>IBM</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>34L9195</MfrPartNumber> 
        <ItemType>Computer-Accessories</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData> 
        <ProductData>
            <Computers>
                 <ProductType>
                 <ComputerComponent></ComputerComponent>
                 </ProductType>
                 <SellerWarrantyDescription>**This is the field I was looking for**</SellerWarrantyDescription>
            </Computers>
        </ProductData>  
    </Product>
  </Message>  
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

The sequence of XML elements of is important to Amazon or it will not work. Although the following elements are empty, however they are required before passing the warranty element.

```
             <ProductType>
                 <ComputerComponent></ComputerComponent>
             </ProductType>
```